# Virtualbox installation error on AWS Workpace

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualbox, amazon-workspaces

below are the details of my OS(command ran :lsb_release -a)

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Amazon
Description:    Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
Release:    2
Codename:   Karoo
```

---

When i'm trying to install the virtual6 getting the below errors(sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.1_6.1.4-136177_Ubuntu_bionic_amd64.deb)

```
dpkg: regarding virtualbox-6.1_6.1.4-136177_Ubuntu_bionic_amd64.deb containing virtualbox-6.1, pre-dependency problem:
 **virtualbox-6.1 pre-depends on debconf (>= 1.1) | debconf-2.0
  debconf is not installed.
  debconf-2.0 is not installed.**
```

I installed the debconf(yum install debconf)

but still showing the same error as above ,am i missing something?

Comment: `deb` packages are for Debian based operating systems. Amazon Linux is based on RHEL and uses RPM packages. Virtualbox will not work well inside of another virtual machine, which is what AWS Workspace is.

Answer (score 0):

From: [AWS Forum > Can you run VirtualBox/VMWare inside Amazon Workspaces](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=905856)

> WorkSpaces are virtual machines themselves, they are unable to run or serve as a hypervisor. Unfortunately, at the moment, WorkSpaces does not support nested virtualization. That said, I would suggest you to try using Bare Metal EC2 instances, which allow full access to the underlying hardware. This would allow you to run your own hypervisor or emulation software.